# Prove $g(x)=xf(x)$ is differentiable at $x=1$ then $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$

Tags: calculus

My approach is to use $\frac{g(x)-g(1)}{x-1}=g'(x)+ r(x)$ where $r(x)\to0$ as $x\to1.$

But I have no idea this approach is right.

Comment: You should have:  $$\frac{g(x)-g(1)}{x-1}=g'(1)+ r(x).$$ It should be $g'(1),$ not $g'(x)$ in your formulation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $f(x)=\frac1x g(x)$ (at least around $x=1$), and $\frac1x$ is differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: I can't get the hang of it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If two functions are differentiable at a point, then so is their product.

Comment: I assumed this question was more about "from the definitions" due to usage of $r(x)$ in the OPs approach.

Comment: You are probably right, though it was not explicitly said.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$\frac{g(x)-g(1)}{x-1}=g'(1)+r(x)$$

where $r(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 1.$

> Note, it should be $g'(1),$ not $g'(x),$ as you've formulated it it in your question. We don't even know that $g'(x)$ exists for any value of $x$ other than $x=1.$

Then using that $g(x)=xf(x)$ you get:

$$\frac{xf(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = g'(1)+r(x)$$

Rewriting, we get $$\begin{align}\frac{xf(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&=\frac{xf(x)-f(x)+f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{f(x)(x-1)}{x-1}+\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\\
&=f(x)+\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}.\end{align}$$

So we have that $$\begin{align}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&=g'(1)-f(x)+r(x)\\
&=g'(1)-f(1)+\left[f(1)-f(x)+r(x)\right]
\end{align}$$

If we then show that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1,$ we know know that $r_1(x)=f(1)-f(x)+r(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 1,$ and then we know that $f'(1)$ exists and is equal to $g'(1)-f(1).$

So the remainder is to show that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$ under these conditions.